# Is it possible to Add New set of input boxes in Jenkins Pipeline with on the fly button click?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Like HTML/JS, is it possible placed on Add button and when user clicking on add each time i need set of input boxed added to the form on the fly during pipeline execution.

Is this possible in Jenkins Pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) plugin.

It allows to write HTML/JS in jenkins build with parameters.

How to write HTML shown on plugin page.